# Clang-format multiple conditions new line

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-format

If I have a code something like this

```
void function()
{
 return XXXXXXXXX && FFFFFFFFFFFFFF && MMMMMMMMMMMMMM;
}
```

How can I convert it in something like this

```
void function()
{
 return XXXXXXXXX && 
     FFFFFFFFFFFFFF && 
     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

clang-format won't break a line like that unless you have reached the line limit, you can align the operands with:

```
AlignOperands: Align
```

you might want to check out

```
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators : All
```

You can find descriptions of these here:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html